# Irreducibility of a module of a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, modules

Let $G = \langle x \rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $p$ ($p$ is a prime). Let $M$ be a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ with basis $\{m_0, m_1, \cdots, m_{p-1}\}$. Define $\rho(x)$ to be $$\rho(x)m_i = \begin{cases}
m_{i+1} & \text{ if } 0 \leq i <p-1, \\
m_0 & \text{ if } i=p-1.\end{cases}$$ Then $\rho$ is the regular representation of $G$.  Set $u_0 = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} m_i$ and $u_i = m_i - m_{i-1}$, $1 \leq i \leq p-1$. Prove that $N_1 = \mathbb Q u_0$ and $N_2 = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\mathbb Q u_i$ are irreducible $G$-submodules of $M$ and $M = N_1 \oplus N_2$.
(Hint: Use that fact that the polynomial $\lambda^{p-1} + \cdots + \lambda +1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.)

MY PROBLEM: how can I prove that irreducibility of $N_2$ using the hint?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Hint: The characteristic polynomial $p(T)$ of the restriction of $\rho(x)$ to any submodule $N'\subset N_2$ has to be a factor of $T^{p-1}+\cdots+T+1$. The degree of $p(T)$ has to be equal to $\dim N'$.</strike>

---

If $N_2$ were not irreducible it would still be semisimple by Maschke. If we have
$$N_2=\bigoplus_{\ell=1}^kM_\ell,$$
for some simple $\Bbb{Q}G$-submodules $M_\ell$, and denote by $p_\ell(T)$ the characteristic polynomial of $\rho(x)$ restricted to $M_\ell, \ell=1,2,\ldots,k$, then we get a factorization for the characteristic polynomial $p(T)$ of $\rho(x)$ on $N_2$:
$$
p(T)=\prod_{\ell=1}^kp_\ell(T).
$$
Moreover, we have $\deg p_\ell(T)=\dim M_\ell$, and that all the factors $p_\ell\in\Bbb{Q}[T]$.

The known irreducibility of $p(T)$ thus implies that $k=1$, and the claim follows.